# PHP Проверить элемент doom элемент на пустоту (длину строки)

Tags: php

Вот так получив нужные элементы, прохожу их чтоб получить ссылки, но в некоторых элементах отсутствует атрибут href, скрипт аварийно завершается на достигнутом элементе без атрибута (Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in), как мне сделать проверку на пустоту и обход ?

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//section/div/ul/li[starts-with(@class, "filter-links")]') AS $node) {
            #var_dump($node->getElementsByTagName('a')); 
            $href   = $node->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
            echo $href."<br>";
```

Вот такой вариант мне не помог

```
if (is_null($node->getElementsByTagName('a'))){ 
                continue;
                }
```

var_dump выводит

```
object(DOMNodeList)#55 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } https://www.site/qqw
object(DOMNodeList)#56 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) } https://www.site/qqwdq
object(DOMNodeList)#55 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

методом тыка, нашел решение )

```
if ($node->getElementsByTagName('a')->length == 0){
                continue;
                }
```